# How Do I config one endpoint for multiple service in WCF?

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf

Is it possible and how to config to just have one endpoint for multiple services in our WCF Service Application?

Thank you

Comment: One service can have 1:n endpoints - but each endpoint belongs to exactly one service. You cannot "share" endpoints across multiple services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean something like:

```
Service1
Service2
Service3
.
.
.
Service n
```

And all services are at one endpoint, say `http://localhost/MyServices/Services`, then I believe the answer is no. The Address, Binding and Contract (ABC) make up the endpoint, and each endpoint must have a unique address.

So even if you tried something like:

**Endpoint 1:**

Address:  http://localhost/MyServices/Services
Binding:  wsHttpBinding
Contract: Service1

**Endpoint 2:**

Address:  http://localhost/MyServices/Services
Binding:  wsHttpBinding
Contract: Service2

You'd run into problems with endpoint 2 as it has the same address as endpoint 1.

[Specifying an Endpoint Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx)

[Hosting Multiple Services](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6d523893-ecfd-411a-87b4-4f01895cb33d/)

Answer (score 1):

Every Service / Binding / Contract combination must use a discrete address and therefore must be a separate endpoint

However, as far as your clients are concerned, as long as you use the same transport protocol you could use the WCF 4 routing service to give a single addressable endpoint and then use other criteria (say action or other SOAP header) to route to the correct service

Answer (score 1):

One work around would be to implement **partial classes** that allow you to separate your content in individual cs files while maintaing a single interface and endpoint. This isn't the most ideal way, because at the end of the day it is still a single class made up of partial classes, but at least it looks like you have separate services because you have a class file for each service.

## Example Structure:

**IMyService.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   string GenericMethod()

   [OperationContract]
   string GetUsers(int companyId)

   [OperationContract]
   string GetMessages(int userId)

}
```

**MyService.cs**

```
//Put any attributes for your service in this class file
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public partial class MyService : IMyService
{
  public string GenericMethod() 
  {
     return "";
  }
}
```

**UserService.cs**

```
public partial class MyService
{
    public string GetUsers(int companyId) 
    {
       return "";
    }
}
```

**MessagingService.cs**

```
public partial class MyService
{
      public string GetMessages(int userId) 
      {
          return "";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a new interface that exposes all the interfaces you want to expose and then have one class that just delegates the request to the right class.